# Loop iteration through list: starting on item X on first loop, going over full list after

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of objects belonging to a class I created:

```
my_list = [item_1, item_2, item_3]
```

Each item has an attribute `.attribute`.

I have a loop wherein the items from my list are iterated through and used to call a function along with the attribute, like so:

```
while True:

    for i in range(3):
        my_function(my_list[i].attribute)
```

My problem: I want to be able to choose which `item` on `my_list` the iteration starts from, but as the loop continues I want the next iterations to begin with the start of `my_list`. In other words, I'd like for the loop to go like this:

`item_2 -> item_3 -> item_1 -> item_2 -> item_3 -> item_1 ....`

or:

`item_3 -> item_1 -> item_2 -> item_3 -> item_1 ...`

As opposed to the standard behavior of:

`item_1 -> item_2 -> item_3 -> item_1 ...`

I'm at a loss as to how to go about it and would appreciate some pointers. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `cycle` and `islice` from `itertools`

```
for i in itertools.islice(itertools.cycle(my_list), start, stop):
    my_func(i.attribute)
```

Treat `start` and `stop` like indices in list slicing `repeating_list[start:stop]`

Comment: didn't you mean _itertools.cycle_?

Comment: Thanks. Will this solution work for a range, two? so instead of `cycle(my_list` can I use `cycle(range(3))` ?

Comment: Yes, `range` objects are iterators

Comment: From the brief testing I have just done, this doesn't seem to be doing what I wanted. It gets the first iteration correctly, but when it's supposed to go over `my_list` again, it again begins from the designated `start` from `itertools.islice`. 

For a loop with `for i in itertools.islice(itertools.cycle(my_list),1,3)` what I am getting is:

`index 1, index 2, index 1, index 2, index 1, index 2....`

while what I need is:

`index 1, index 2, index 0, index 1, index 2, index 0...`

Comment: If you are passing `islice` 1 and 3 for `start` and `stop` it is only giving you 2 values.  use `itertools.islice(itertools.cycle(my_list),1,None)` for it to keep going indefinitely. You don't need it wrapped in a while loop

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I'm just misunderstanding the question, but you could simply put the first call to `my_function` outside of the for loop, and then continue normally once inside.

```
my_function(my_list[3].attribute)
for i in range(3):
    my_function(my_list[i].attribute)
```

You could then use a conditional to determine which `item` is called (or if it is called at all) outside the for loop.